# If else formula on a boolean column in crystal reports

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, boolean

My column has 0 and 1  value.
I want if column value is 1 then "active" else "inactive".
My formula is

```
      If{tablename.colname} =1 then    "active" else "inactive".
```

It gives me an error a boolean is required here.

Answer (score 0):

If your colname is boolean and you are comparing it with integer 0 or 1 then you get the error. It seems the types mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Change to: `If {tablename.colname} then "active" else "inactive"`